# Visual Basic - How to continually check textboxes for text then enable button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So I'm trying to make my own personal to-do list inside of Visual Basic (Using Visual Studio) and I want to disable the "Add Item" button until something has been entered into the textbox.

I've tried checking the textbox for text on form load but I don't know how to dynamically check the textbox for an input then enable/disable the button.

Code I've tried:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        If txtItem.Text = "" Then
            btnAddItem.Enabled = False
        Else
            btnAddItem.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

EDIT: Nevermind I have figured it out. I took out the code from form1_load and wrote:

btnAddItem.Enabled = False

and added:

If txtItem.Text() = "" Then
            btnAddItem.Enabled = False
        Else
            btnAddItem.Enabled = True
        End If

to the text_changed event of the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your form looks like this:

```
Items:
    [ ] Feed fish
    [ ] Enslave world
    [X] Do laundry
    [ ] Push Plumbus through the Grumbo

Add item:
    Task name: [_________]
    [Add Item]
```

You don't need to continuously check the textbox - you only need to subscribe to the `event` that's raised whenever the textbox's `.Text` changes. This is [the `TextChanged` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx). Note this event is raised when the text is changed by your own code, not just user input: this may or may not be desireable (use `KeyDown` or `KeyPress` to handle those events).

(As a tip: generally speaking polling (checking something continuously in a loop or timer interval) is a bad idea because it wastes CPU time. In a self-contained program like this your program receives actual event information when things change and you can handle those events exactly when things change instead of using a poll loop - polling is only really needed when you're sampling an external system, such as a temperature sensor or serial line - and in those cases there are libraries or hardware that will handle the polling for you and expose events when data changes instead).

You can set an event-handler in VB.NET using the `Handles` keyword instead of manually wiring-up event-handlers (this does add some voodoo to your program, you can't use `Handles` for dynamically-added controls, for example)

```
Private Sub txtItem_TextChanged(sender As Object, e as EventArgs) Handles txtItem.TextChanged

    Me.btnAddItem.Enabled = Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace( Me.txtItem.Text )

End Sub
```

Comment: I managed to fix it myself with the same logic but instead with an If/Else statement. Any major difference/advantages/disadvantages between the two methods that I should be aware of? This will be for my own personal use only so as long as it works its not too much of an issue for me.

Comment: @shanetemple90 Just code-succinctness. My shorter version may be preferable as it uses less space if you have a longer code block.

Comment: What happens if there is a space? `Me.txtItem.Text.Length > 0` will allow a space to trip it...

Comment: @Codexer I've changed my solution to use `String.IsNullOrWhitespace` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but remove `Length` from that check ;), good solution btw.